# Almacenar en un txt datos de contacto provistos por un usuario

Tags: html, python, flask

Estoy seguro que el error está en la función write_to_file(). Esto lo digo porque en la función submit_form(), se imprimen los datos (simplemente para fines de testeo) provistos por el usuario, previamente estos siendo convertidos en un diccionario, y efectivamente cuando reviso la consola del servidor, aparecen dichos datos en forma de diccionario.

Sin embargo, cuando voy a revisar el archivo database.txt, simplemente sigue en blanco.

server.py:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<string:page_name>')
def html_page(page_name):
    return render_template(page_name)

def write_to_file(data):
    with open('database.txt', mode='a') as database:
        email = data['email']
        subject = data['subject']
        message = data['message']
        file = database.write(f'\n{email},{subject},{message}')

@app.route('/submit_form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submit_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        print(data)
        write_to_file(data)
        return redirect('/thank_you.html')
    else:
        return 'something went wrong. Try again'
```

contact.html (selección de lo que considero importante)

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
               <form action="/submit_form" method="post" class="reveal-content">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="subject" type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message"></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Send</button>
                    </div>
```

Consola del servidor, se ve claramente que el diccionario se genera correctamente. Por esto es que mencioné que no creo que sea un problema en la función submit_form(), ni en el HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se si el with ya cierra el txt, pero si no, python necesita que cierres el archivo con `tuarchivo.close()` para guardar los cambios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es la expuesta por Dante.